# Covert name part after "ACCOUNTS\\" to lower case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, lowercase

I have web method to get user from this.User.Identity.Name.string username  = "ACCOUNTS\Ninja.Developer" I want to convert username part after "ACCOUNTS\" to lower case  to be username  = "ACCOUNTS\ninja.developer"

```
public User GetUser()
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Username = this.User.Identity.Name,<-- convert it here 
        IsAuthenticated = this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
    };


    return user;
}
```

note: double \ not single \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace` to achieve it :

```
Username = Regex.Replace(this.User.Identity.Name, @"(?<=ACCOUNTS\\).+", n => n.Value.ToLower()),
```

The regex pattern `(?<=ACCOUNTS\\).+` will match for anything after `ACCOUNTS\`, and the match is then replaced by its lower case equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
var Identity = this.User.Identity.Name;
var Username = Identity.Split('\\')[0] + @"\\" + Identity.Split('\\')[2].ToLower();
```

Of course you should check before in the name have the `\` character, etc.

Comment: i hope it doesn't throw an error, since single '\' is identified as escape sequence. if it does then"\\" should work.

Comment: it "\\" not single '\'

Comment: Edited for handling double `\\`. There just one more element in the array

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, you can use Regex or Split, but here's a substring approach specific to your case.

```
var user = new User
{
    Username = this.User.Identity.Name.Substring(0,9) + this.User.Identity.Name.Substring(9, name.Length - 9).ToLower(),
    IsAuthenticated = this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
};
```